# How to copy files to home directory of the user

Tags: linux, windows, macos, qt, qmake

I want qmake to create a sub directory in `/home` for my own config files like `/home/user/.myapp`. But how can I get the home directory path in qmake?

Comment: you can use echo the $HOME env. variable to get to know the home path

Comment: Ok thats a possible solution but will this work on OSX, Linux and Windows?

Comment: It will not work on Windows, you can use combination of %SystemDrive% and %HOMEPATH% as a separate case for windows though. Looks like there's no internal qmake way to find that path though.

Comment: @shi I have no idea about windows but I think it may work on mac ,or you can also set env. like HOME if not present in mac

Comment: @user2760375 Ok thanks a lot. I guess I will use this as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QMake is a build system only available on the development machine at build time, and such won't help you to create directories on the machine where your software is deployed. To get storage locations at application runtime, use [QStandardPaths](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstandardpaths.html) (Qt 5) or [QDesktopServices::storageLocation()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#storageLocation) (Qt 4). To get the user's home directory, use [QDir::homePath()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#homePath).
Then simply create the required directories and files programmatically, in your program.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the best way

Comment: You shouldn't use homePath + ".myapp" dir for all platforms. On Windows and Mac OS X application settings should be kept in different directory

Comment: Right, that's why there's QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation etc.

Comment: But shouldn't homePath + ".myapp" work on Windows as well? There is C:/Users/username/ or something similiar on Windows...

Comment: @shi: The path will exist, but that’s not where applications are expected to put their data. A well-behaved Windows application puts things to something like %APPDATA%/ApplicationName.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld where should data installed by the application but dedicated to a user be located on windows ? sometimes data is not intended to be shared among all users.